# Can I JOIN two tables in different databases with only one match with sum values for each row that repeat in tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 databases with product table with ID and quantities like this:

```
db1.products
ID    Stock
1     10
2     20
3     30

db2.products
ID    Stock
1     3
2     5
4     40
```

And need join, sum similar ID´s and show unique ID´s with their stock like this output

```
ID    Stock
1     13 (sum of same ID´s)
2     25
3     30
4     40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` for the 2 tables and then `group by id` to aggregate:

```
select t.id, sum(t.stock) stock
from ( 
  select * from db1.products
  union all
  select * from db2.products
) t
group by t.id
```

Comment: Thanks @forpas, this code work like I need: 

`SELECT t.int_produto_id_pk, SUM(t.int_produto_qtdestoque) FROM (
SELECT int_produto_id_pk, int_produto_qtdestoque FROM db1.tab_produto
UNION ALL
SELECT int_produto_id_pk, int_produto_qtdestoque FROM db2.tab_produto) AS t
GROUP BY int_produto_id_pk;`

Comment: If there are other columns in the 2 tables, of course you must specify in the 2 select lists of the union subquery the 2 columns that you want to return.

Comment: If there is a column product_active in both tables then add the condition `select * from db1.products where product_active = 1 union all select * from db2.products where product_active = 1` or: `select t.id, sum(t.stock) stock from ( select * from db1.products union all select * from db2.products ) t where t.product_active = 1 group by t.id`